# Calculate a recursive sequence using Wallis'integral

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have this sequence defined by :
 $$u_1=1\\ u_{n+1}u_n=n,\ \ n>1$$

How can we prove that ??
$$u_n=nW_n\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2}\biggr)^{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}-1}{2}}$$
Where $W_n$ is the Wallis integral.
$$W_n= \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx\ dx$$
Best regards.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Thank you Mr @Saad i'll try to improve it

Comment: Thank you Mr Saad, i don't understand, can you explain more ?!

Comment: It's easy to see that $u_{n+2}=\dfrac{n+1}nu_n$, and to derive $W_{n+2}=\dfrac{n+1}nW_n$, you may use integration by parts. Also note that $u_1=W_1$ and $u_2=W_2$.

Comment: Ok brother i'll see if it works ... thank's again for giving importance to my question

Comment: Ok my fiend ... have a nice day